# How to pass a compatible union type from one overloaded function to another in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've got two functions that each take a union type as input, and whose output matches the input's type. One of those functions calls the other. I believe I should be able to represent that using overloaded type definitions, like this:

```js
function f1(input: number): number;
function f1(input: string): string;
function f1(input: string | number): string | number {
    return input;
}

function f2(input: number): number;
function f2(input: string): string;
function f2(input: string | number): string | number {
    return f1(input);
}
```

However, [this results in a type error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAjAChmADiKAuRMEAWwCMBTAJwEoCiyqBuAKFElgWXUx30QGcolTAHNaAoaJZto8JKgzZcBQcLAjEAH0IkKNFZPVadDSogDezRNcSVyUEJSQ9cLAL7NW4WZ2AAmRV46XSpxej1pbw55AJc+VVFxBPVI9jlkWKV4ww1tcNCDNVyTPQsrGzsHJy5A3Gp3IA):

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(input: number): number', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(input: string): string', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2769)
```

Is there another way to properly represent that these functions preserve their input type? Are overloaded types the way to go, or could I make this work using generics somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript does not automatically synthesize call signatures on unions from overloaded call signatures.  There's a longstanding open issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107), asking for this, but I'm not sure if it will ever be implemented.  For now you have to do "something else", which includes any number of workarounds:

---

One workaround is to add the union call signature that you want to see:

```
function f1(input: number): number;
function f1(input: string): string;
function f1(input: string | number): string | number; // added
function f1(input: string | number): string | number {
    return input;
}

function f2(input: number): number;
function f2(input: string): string;
function f2(input: string | number): string | number {
    return f1(input); // okay
}
```

---

Another workaround is to use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) and [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) to replace your overload with a single call signature:

```
function f1<T extends number | string>(input: T): T extends number ? number : string;
function f1(input: string | number): string | number {
    return input;
}

function f2(input: number): number;
function f2(input: string): string;
function f2(input: string | number): string | number {
    return f1(input); // okay
}
```

---

Another workaround is to use conditional logic when calling `f1()` so that its argument is only ever `string` or `number` and never `string | number`:

```
function f2(input: number): number;
function f2(input: string): string;
function f2(input: string | number): string | number {
    return typeof input === "number" ? f1(input) : f1(input); // okay
}
```

---

Finally, the ultimate workaround is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
function f2(input: number): number;
function f2(input: string): string;
function f2(input: string | number): string | number {
    return f1(input as any) as string | number; // make it work
}
```

---

The workarounds represent tradeoffs between complexity, redundancy, and type safety.  I'm sure there are other workarounds also; it's up to you to decide which one of these, if any, is best for your use case.  Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBAJmgygSwOagBcBXAJ2QG8AoSpWpAMyOHgOwHtgGBGACm2BhECALiTAiYAEYQSASlHipMgNw06jZqw7c+AoaKgES-XPKSHjwXKroMmLdp3q9+gkeaMmkAHzETpcgaeVj5+SiTKSAD0UUggGBBoarQaDtrOum5BlrihigFmFl6++TJIVLa2ZMQknK5CNnQAvtS2qVpOAEyZ+mEFCv4qyXaajgzd9e5FVoXB1sPtY-QTelNzeYOBHjkb4eXDVRA1Ti6rspExSGwA1iAAnsMtLZSgkLAIyADiEMAy2PAAYQ4aGwHRAABt9gt7B1uAAeAAqSAgAA8CD80FA+mVfNNcAA+HruBFmJGo9HATHYkhIAD81KQ2RMjRSMKWpyy22K1NmOxKm32lTo1VIdVWLKQzzabPSK05pS2Coli1lRKZM3V82lo1Vk01u36XJC-L2FSFSBFtR0k3O0ViN3uj0oz1e0DgiCQ31+xkBwNBjghUO1aROap5A3Cyplob1RtMmqjOpjq31JsNeINZTNQstYrcEqaSFa6mj4zDCrMSuhSbLsbxvOZ1ZDtZTcczWwzaazB2FR1FSAIdxgEDY9CQkyQAF5p0gAEQK2d061nRnLty2y4Oh62Z4u8Buj6oKBQGSw7NF4OwjKxisRgKJ5vX1v1hNNq8c3qd8Ntrs08+HY5x3FJ03yWOVelvakHyvcC1hyBsrGgsCwy-SDUIFf9e0Ap83DiLEQGAO5ZDwn8oLtJAwBAa5kFBJAAHc2BIa4QKaIA)

Comment: Excellent overview of the possible solutions - probably not a coincidence that we came up with the first two (either seems reasonable to me) independently already :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adding the union overload does the trick : function f1(input: string | number): string | number;

```
function f1(input: number): number;
function f1(input: string): string;
function f1(input: string | number): string | number;
function f1(input: string | number): string | number {
    return input;
}

function f2(input: number): number;
function f2(input: string): string;
function f2(input: string | number): string | number {
    return f1(input);
}

const resultF2Num = f2(12);     // Number
const resultF2Str = f2('12');   // String
const resultF1Num = f1(12);     // Number
const resultF1Str = f1('12');   // String
```

Comment: ~~That does make it compile; however, it loses the information that the output type is the same as the input type, defeating the point of the overloads, no?~~ Never mind, that does work: TypeScript applies the first matching overload. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way that [seems to work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhARgDwBVkFMAeMuEAJgM7JkwBOcEA5sgD7IRgC2ARrtQHwAUdAA5gYALmRYAlBJwEipClVoNkAfko06jCWy48A3KEixEKdIIgjxmlYxZ7u1Gbe3NWHJ8gDewZP+RqXBgwahRhUSMAX2BjaHgkVAAmbDxCYnJXVQdPHgEIm2lZNIVM5TcNctVdXOo400SQJMtrCSr7D31nNq1szq9fAMDg0PM0FtEpaNioJCpkIioANQBDABs4EjQeu2QAXmT+AHIyBHZcLPojqeBZiHnFmFWNkiSarv3DgBYkm7uH3BUACSEAAbutNu8vAcmscIAgYMgVv0eNcDEA), by defining my overloads as [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types):

```js
function f1<T extends string | number>(input: T): T extends string ? string : number;
function f1(input: string | number): string | number {
    return input;
}

function f2<T extends string | number>(input: T): T extends string ? string : number
function f2(input: string | number): string | number {
    return f1(input);
}

const testValid1: string = f2('some string');
const testValid2: number = f2(42);
const testInvalid: number = f2('not a number');
```