# Overload signatures, union types and "No overload matches this call" error

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Imagine a TypeScript (4.2.2) function that receives a `string` or a `Promise<string>` and returns an answer using the same type it has originally received, for example:

```js
function trim(textOrPromise) {
    if (textOrPromise.then) {
        return textOrPromise.then(value => result.trim());
    }
    return textOrPromise.trim();
}
```

I'd like to define the signature of such function using generics to indicate that passing in a `Promise` always results in a `Promise`, and passing in a `string` results in a `string`

To do that, I define the following overloads:

```js
function trim(text: Promise<string>): Promise<string>
function trim(text: string): string
function trim(text: any): any {
    if (text.then) {
        return text.then(result => result.trim());  // returns Promise<string>
    }
    return text.trim();                             // returns string
}
```

This transpiles correctly as long as the parameter is defined explicitly as `string` or a `Promise<string>`:

```js
let value: string
trim(value)                          // fine
```

```js
let value: Promise<string>
trim(value)                          // fine
```

However, when I define the parameter using a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html)  (`Promise<string> | string`):

```js
let value: Promise<string> | string
trim(value)                          // error: TS2769
```

I get the following transpilation error:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
   Overload 1 of 2, '(text: Promise<string>): Promise<string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | Promise<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<string>'.
       Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Promise<string>'.
   Overload 2 of 2, '(text: string): string', gave the following error.
     Argument of type 'string | Promise<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
       Type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Interestingly enough, when I add the union type to the function signature, the example transpiles and behaves correctly

```js
function trim(text: Promise<string>): Promise<string>
function trim(text: string): string
function trim(text: Promise<string> | string): Promise<string> | string
function trim(text: any): any {
    if (text.then) {
        return text.then(result => result.trim());
    }
    return text.trim();
}

let value: Promise<string> | string
trim(value)                          // fine
```

With this last implementation, TypeScript knows that when a function receives a `Promise` it will return a `Promise`, and when it receives a `string` it returns a `string`. As opposed to a union of `Promise<string> | string` as the third overload would suggest.

I'd be grateful if someone could explain this behaviour and the reason behind having to add an overload for union types.

Comment: I would suggest changing the title to include that question is about "overload signatures" usage and explanation why they should be written the way it does.

Comment: Good point, thanks

Comment: This is an interesting question in terms of the **"why?"**  I can tell you what it's doing and why that fails.  Typescript is checking your variable of type `Promise<string> | string` against each overload individually.  The union is not assignable to either of its members so there is no overload signature that accepts `Promise<string> | string`.  But why can't it split up the union before checking?  I don't know.

Comment: Thanks Linda, exactly. I can use the third overload or conditional types to get around it, but I'd like to understand the mechanics behind this behaviour.

Comment: @Jan I found the GitHub issues about it: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1805 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107 Lots of reading in there.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61596397/how-to-pass-a-compatible-union-type-from-one-overloaded-function-to-another-in-t

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Passing Unions to An Overload

Typescript is not able to "split up" the union before checking it against your overload signatures. It is checking your variable of type `Promise<string> | string` against each overload individually. The union is not assignable to either of its members so there is no overload signature that accepts `Promise<string> | string`.

This is a known behavior and some of the GitHub issues about this date back years.

- [Support overload resolution with type union arguments #14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107)
- [Union types not working with old-style overloads #1805](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1805)

The argument against changing the typescript behavior seems to be that the number of possible combinations can explode quickly when you have a function with multiple arguments that each accept multiple types.

Since typescript doesn't support this on its own, you have to manually add an overload that accepts the union and returns the union, like you have already done.  Note that the implementation signature (the last line of the overload) does not count as one of the overloads.  So just having the union in the implementation signature is not enough.

```
function trim(text: Promise<string>): Promise<string>;
function trim(text: string): string;
function trim(text: Promise<string> | string): Promise<string> | string;
function trim(text: Promise<string> | string): Promise<string> | string {
  if (typeof text === "string") {
    return text.trim();
  } else {
    return text.then(result => result.trim());
  }
}
```

#### Generics

We don't have this problem when using generics instead of overloads because `extends` includes the union.  `T extends A | B` means that `T` can be `A`, `B`, or the union `A | B` (or any more refined version of these, which I'll get into in a bit).

```
function trim<T extends Promise<string> | string>(text: T): T {
```

However generics raise their own issues when it comes to the implementation of the function because refining the type of the variable `text` doesn't refine the type of the generic `T`.  That behavior makes sense in general, given that the type `T` could be a union.

It's frustrating here especially because we are returning the same type as the input.  So if we know that `text` is a `string` then we know that `T` must include `string` so it should be fine to return a `string`, right?  Nope.

It feels like we only have three possibilities (`string`, `Promise<string>`, `Promise<string> | string`).  But `extends` opens infinite possible types for `T` that are refinements of those.  If `T` is the literal string `" A "` then the `string` `"A"` that we return from `text.trim()` really *isn't* assignable to `T`. So we've solved one issue but created another.  We have to make `as` assertions to avoid errors like:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | Promise'.(2322)

And there are some weird edge cases where those assertions might be incorrect.

```
function trim<T extends Promise<string> | string>(text: T): T {
  if (text instanceof Promise) {
    return text.then((result) => result.trim()) as T;
  }
  return (text as string).trim() as T;
}

const a = trim(' ' as Promise<string> | string);  // type: string | Promise<string>
const b = trim(' ');                              // type: ' ' -- actually wrong!
const c = trim(' ' as string);                    // type: string
const d = trim(new Promise<string>(() => ' '));   // type: Promise<string>
const e = trim(new Promise<' '>(() => ' '));      // type: Promise<' '> -- wrong again!
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Nr2vDN)

So I would prefer the overloaded version even though you need that extra line.

Comment: Thanks Linda! Your explanation and the tickets you've linked were of great help. I've gone with the overloaded version (the last one I described in my original post), but instead of repeating the last overload signature, I've typed the function itself with `any`, which is what TypeScript docs seem to recommend - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Comment: @Jan the reason that I didn't use `any` was to avoid errors in the implementation.  I have `noImplicitAny` on so I get an error in the `then(result =>` part "Parameter 'result' implicitly has an 'any' type"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Conditional types`?

in your case, it will look something like this

```
function trim<T extends string | Promise<string>>(
 text: T
): T extends Promise<string> ? Promise<string> : string {
  ....
}
```

Also, you asked about why in order for it to type check it's required to do `overload signatures`

```
function trim(text: Promise<string>): Promise<string>
function trim(text: string): string
```

This is essentially a way of telling TS that if `string` is passed return type should be `string` and if `Promise` is passed return type should be `Promise`. Because TS doesn't have any runtime type checking mechanics it cannot determine at runtime a type of value you've passed to function.

Also, you don't need a final overloading statement with `any.

```
function trim(text: any): any {


function trim(text: Promise<string> | string): Promise<string> | string {
```

would be enough since it accommodates every case you declared using `overload signatures` above.

your final code would look like this

```
function trim(text: Promise<string>): Promise<string>;
function trim(text: string): string;
function trim(text: Promise<string> | string): Promise<string> | string;
function trim(text: Promise<string> | string): Promise<string> | string {
  if (text instanceof Promise) {
   return text.then((result) => result.trim());
  }
  return text.trim();
}
```

I hope I've answered your question.

Comment: I edited your code because you actually need the final line of the overload which accepts `Promise<string> | string` to be written twice since the implementation signature doesn't count as an overload.  Without having it as an overload you get the same "no overload matches this call" error as before when calling `trim` on a variable whose type is the union.

Comment: That said, I don't think this really answers the question because OP already knows that they can add an explicit overload signature for the union and it works.  The question is more about WHY this is needed which is a hard question that I can't answer either.

Comment: How would you write an implementation for your conditional type? If you check the type of `text`, Typescript isn't smart enough to realize that your check also defines the generic type and you get an error when trying to return a value.